# How can we do the process of appending excel from dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to write a code to parse some data from network output with a loop on set of devices and append the results in a dictionary and then write each dictionary keys and values into an excel sheet

The problem I am facing at the moment that the key values are printed as column headers every time the loop is executed

```
dictionary = {"key1":[],"key2":[],"key3":[]}
dictionary["key1"].append(parse_value1)
dictionary["key2"].append(parse_value2)
dictionary_to_df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
dictionary_to_df("csv path,mode = "a",index = False, header = True)
```

output is something like that:

| key1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| key 1 | key2 | key3 |
| value4 | value5 | value6 |

however I would like to get the output as below

| key1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| value4 | value5 | value6 |

Comment: What's `devices_df`? For the second, third, use `header=None`.

Comment: I corrected the name , Tested and now working as desired :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try concating all the dataframes generating from the loop to one bigger dataframe

```py
dfs = []

for loop
    dictionary = {"key1":[],"key2":[],"key3":[]}
    dictionary["key1"].append(parse_value1)
    dictionary["key2"].append(parse_value2)
    dictionary_to_df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
    dfs.append(dictionary_to_df)

df = pd.concat([dfs])
df.to_csv("csv path", mode = "a",index = False, header = True)
```

Or make the `dictionary` is global for the `for-loop`

```py
dictionary = {"key1":[],"key2":[],"key3":[]}

for loop
    dictionary["key1"].append(parse_value1)
    dictionary["key2"].append(parse_value2)

dictionary_to_df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
dictionary_to_df.to_csv("csv path", mode = "a",index = False, header = True)
```

Or check the file header existence

```py
for loop
    dictionary = {"key1":[],"key2":[],"key3":[]}
    dictionary["key1"].append(parse_value1)
    dictionary["key2"].append(parse_value2)
    dictionary_to_df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
    with open("csv path", 'a') as f:
        dictionary_to_df.to_csv(f,mode = "a",index=False, header=not f.tell())
```

Answer (score 0):

use simple code (pd.DataFrame.from_dict):

```
dictionary = {"key1":[],"key2":[]}
parse_value1=["value1","value2","value3"]
parse_value2=["value4","value5","value6"]
dictionary["key1"].extend(parse_value1)
dictionary["key2"].extend(parse_value2)
dictionary_to_df  =pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
dictionary_to_df.to_csv("test.csv",mode = "a",index = False, header = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by

1. Defining the header outside the loop
2. write the header to `output.csv` file
3. convert the dictionary into a dataframe
4. append the dataframe into `output.csv` file with `header option = false`